# Obtener domino de una URL vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

Bueno tengo este problema, tengo una url (String):

`https://www.linkedin.com/?trk=msn-top-ve`

y quiero obtener el dominio que es :

```
www.linkedin.com
```

también quiero obtener el dominio para las url que son : https://ww5.wpepro.net/ etc..  solo quiero el dominio : (**ww5.wpepro.net**)

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba con una expresión regular, como `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)`

Comment: Revisa [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) y usa la expresion que te he puesto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim uri As New Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/?trk=msn-top-ve")
Dim dominio as String=uri.Host
```

Comment: Aritz, gracias por respodner pero recuerda que respuestas solo con codigo no ayudan más que para ser copiadas y pegadas. Has de explicar su funciomaniento para que el OP y futuros usuarios lo puedan entender indiferentemente de su conocimiento al respecto. Un saludo